# push into array while it is being looped

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Here's a snippet of my code. I understand that it is generally advised against to modify an `array` whilst it is being looped, however in this scenario I think it is the right thing to do and saves resources.

```
$levels = array($post);
foreach ($levels as $level) {
    $next_sibling = get_next_sibling_page($level);
    if ($next_sibling) {
        $next_page = $next_sibling;
        break 1;
    } else if ($level->post_parent) {
        array_push($levels, get_page($level->post_parent));
    }
}
```

The idea is that the `foreach` would reiterate with the pushed value `if ($level->post_parent)`, I can see that the `if` statement is resolving to true and the `array` is being pushed to however the `foreach` does not reiterate and only runs the one time.

Does anyone know how I can recursively continue my foreach until `$level->post_parent` resolves to false?

Comment: "Does anyone know how I can recursively continue my foreach.." - with recursion

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Do you know something I don't?

Answer (score 2):

To modify array which is being used in foreach pass array by referance.

```
foreach (&$levels as $level) {
   .....
}
```

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&'`, I have seen passing the value as a reference but there are no examples of passing the array as reference,